# Transition padding from the box's edge

Tags: html, css

I want to create a box (div) in which padding increases when hovered. Actually it's a full-screen button.

I tried:

```
.full_screen {
width:20px;
height:20px;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
border-radius:2px;
position:absolute;
transition:all 0.6s; //important property
left:82%;
}

.full_screen:hover {
padding-top:10px; //!important property
padding-right:10px; //important property
}
```

I made padding increase from top and right but it didn't work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ja290w94/ works fine. with the exception of the `//` stuff. that's not how to do comments in css.

Comment: In your code it seems to me that there is no issue. If this is the all CSS that effecting that section then it should work. It would be great if you put the HTML and CSS into JS Fiddle then we might help you.

Comment: @guest , i know about that but, i want it to have transition padding to upside and right side i.e. the edge of the box. But, If you see in the fiddle that's not quite happening

Comment: _“in which when hovered padding increases from the edge”_ – where else would it increase “from”? And if @guest’s fiddle doesn’t show what you want – then please explain _more clearly_ what it actually is that you want.

Comment: Do you want the overall element dimensions to stay the same, so that the `x` (in guest’s fiddle) would be moving around in the button instead? Then you either have to decrease width and height accordingly, or use `box-sizing` to make them stay the same, independent of whatever padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left:

> For absolutely positioned elements (those with position: absolute or position: fixed), it [the `left` property] specifies the distance between the left margin edge of the element and the left edge of its containing block.

```
left:82%;
```

CSS interprets this as "keep the left edge of this box 82% from the left edge of the containing block." So as it is, the left edge stays in place when the size changes due to the padding.

[Demo, using the code in the question](http://jsfiddle.net/ja290w94/)

What you wanted was to keep the right edge in place. To do that, you can specify `right` in your CSS instead of `left`.

```
right:18%;
```

[Demo with the above property](http://jsfiddle.net/ja290w94/1/)